# Assigning char value from char pointer with strtok

Tags: c

I'm struggling with getting the data I need from  `strtok`. Being a C beginner working with pointers and such for the first time is hard.

Im basically reading a file that contains some numbers with an empty space between them `" "`. I can successfully read the file and print the separation I get from `strtok` but the problem comes when I want to use the value I get from `strtok`.

I have a type called `Cell` which looks like this

```
typedef struct{
    //Other things
    char value;
}Cell;
```

I know that `strtok` returns a `char*`, but I would need to store an actual `char` inside `Cell`. Is it there a way to do this with `strtok` or should I look for another function to use?.

I could also store a `char*` inside the `Cell` but, when I exit the method in which `strtok` is used, wouldn't that reference to a char dissapear?

Comment: You can call `sscanf()` to convert the token to a number, then store that in the struct.

Comment: To dereference a pointer, add a star in front:  `char* p = "a"; char c = *p;`  You can also use an index: `char *p = "a"; char c = p[0];`

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That will just get the first character of the token, not the whole token.

Comment: You're right.  The question needs some code in it.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code!, ill update it if necessary. @Barmar do you mean using `sscanf()` instead of `strtok()` or doing something like `char c = sscanf(str)`

Comment: using atoi() would be the way to go, then.  char i = atoi(p);  Simpler, faster and safer to use than sscanf in this case.

Comment: You can use cppreference dot com for C library help.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy avoid recommending `atoi()` as it provides **zero** error checking and if you pass it say `"cat"` it happily returns `0` without any error. Best to use `strtol` where full error-checking is provided, or at least `sscanf` where a *matching-failure* would be detected.

Comment: The list of traps in using sscanf is long, especially for a beginer.

Comment: question is unclear, adding some code may make this clear